# C# object oriented read text file

Tags: c#, readfile, datagridviewcolumn

I read the text files in the folder, I get the absolute value of each column, and I showed the maximum value and the name of the file in the datagrid. But I need to write my methods in a class and call it in form.cs, not in form.cs. Can you help me?
my code is like this:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Desktop\..");
FileInfo[] Files = info.GetFiles("*.txt"); 
List<string> list = new List<string>();
List<Double> values= new List<Double>();

foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
         string name = info.Name;

         list.Add(file.Name);
         string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Desktop\..\" + file, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254")); 

         values.AddRange(MultiColumns(lines));

    }

private List<Double> MultiColumns(String[] strs)
    {
        double col1Max = 0; 
        double col2Max = 0;
        double col3Max = 0;
        var list = new List<Double>();
        var format = new NumberFormatInfo();
        format.NegativeSign = "-";
        format.NumberNegativePattern = 1;
        format.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

        foreach (var row in strs)
        {
            var rowElements = row.Split(',');


            Double temp1 = 0;
            Double temp2 = 0;
            Double temp3 = 0;

            Double.TryParse(rowElements[0], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, format, out temp1);
            Double.TryParse(rowElements[1], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, format, out temp2);
            Double.TryParse(rowElements[2], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, format, out temp3);


            col1Max = getMax(col1Max, temp1);
            col2Max = getMax(col2Max, temp2);
            col3Max = getMax(col3Max, temp3);

        }

        list.Add(col1Max);
        list.Add(col2Max);
        list.Add(col3Max);
        return list;
    }

    private double getMax(double colMax, double temp)
    {

        //Math.Abs(colMax);
        if (temp < 0)
        {
            temp *= -1;
        }
        if (temp > colMax)
        {
            colMax = temp;
        }
        return colMax;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example of your file?

Comment: -1,-5,0
-1,-1,-1
-1,3,-3
-1,1,-1

Comment: I need to show the maximum value of each column. It does not evaluate negative numbers as absolute

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do all these with Linq as one-liner:

```
var results = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Desktop\..","*.txt")
   .Select(file => new { file, max = File.ReadAllText(file).Split(',')
   .Select(x=> double.Parse(x.Trim())).Max()});
```

If you want to also get the maximum of all max values:

```
allMax = result.Max(x => x.max);
```

to Test:

```
foreach(var item in results)
   Console.WriteLine($"file: {item.file} - max: {item.max}");
```

Comment: How do I get the maximum value of all columns using linq?

Comment: you mean all coulmns of all files? (one value for all)?

Comment: a text file has three columns only. I find the maximum value of each column, so three values ​​will come from each text file

Comment: c# 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ReadAllLines()' and no accesible extension method.. 
I get an error

Comment: `File` should be uppercase. `File.ReadAllLines` not `file.ReadAllLines`

Comment: File.ReadAllLines- I wrote that

Comment: Do you have a reference to the `System.IO` namespace?

Comment: @Saggio the namespace is in her code (unless she has removed it)

Comment: but I get the error I wrote above values.AddRange(lines.SelectMany(x => x.Split(',').Select(y => Double.Parse(y, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, format))));system.formatexception:'ınput string was not ina correct format

Comment: `input string was not ina correct format` means that it is a string that can not be parsed as double, so 1.please make sure that they are parseable 2.trim it before parsing to make sure that there is no spaces

Comment: Its row consists of three columns. in that: -1,-5,0

Comment: oh I thought they are on different rows, please check my edited answer.

Comment: console does not work in windows form implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string folder = @"D:\Desktop\";
            ReadTextFile readTextFile = new ReadTextFile(folder);
            List<double> absolute = readTextFile.values.Select(x => Math.Abs(x)).ToList();
            double max = readTextFile.values.OrderByDescending(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = readTextFile.dt;
        }


    }

    public class ReadTextFile
    {
        public List<string> list { get; set; }
        public List<Double> values { get; set; }
        public DataTable dt { get; set; }
        public ReadTextFile(string folder)
        {
            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
            FileInfo[] Files = info.GetFiles("*.txt");
            list = new List<string>();
            values = new List<Double>();
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("max1", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("max2", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("max3", typeof(double));

            NumberFormatInfo format = new NumberFormatInfo();
            format.NegativeSign = "-";
            format.NumberNegativePattern = 1;
            format.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";


            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {

                string name = info.Name;


                list.Add(file.Name);
                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(folder + file,
                                                            Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254"));
                try
                {
                    values.AddRange(lines.Skip(1).SelectMany(x => x.Split(',').Take(3).Select(y => Double.Parse(y, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, format))));
                    for(int row = 1; row < lines.Length; row++)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(lines[row].Split(',').Take(3).Select(y => Double.Parse(y, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, format)));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bad data in file : '{0}'", file.Name);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the maximum value of all columns using linq?

Comment: FileInfo[] Files = info.GetFiles("*.txt"); 
System.IO.IOException: 'The directory name is invalid. 
I get the error

Comment: I just used the folder name from your code.  If you still have the two dots then you are moving up the the folder D:\ which is not valid.

Comment: improved, but now in this code Double.TryParse(rowElements[1], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, format, out temp2); System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'The index was out of array bounds.' 
it gives an error

Comment: absolute value Math.ABS() HOW CAN I DO İT

Comment: What is the issue?  Should be simple.

Comment: @Angelia "I need to write my code using linq " I don't see any indication of this statement in your original post... what has changed?

Comment: use linq to get the maximum value of the columns. I forgot to add to the title section

Comment: thank you so much..so how do I make the maximum of columns using linq instead of list

Comment: values.AddRange(lines.SelectMany(x => x.Split(',').Select(y => Double.Parse(y, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, format))));system.formatexception:'ınput string was not ina correct format'

Comment: The file probably has a header row with text so I added a Skip(1).

Comment: Can you hove to find what the data is in the line?  Do you only need first three columns from each line?  Try : SelectMany(x => x.Split(',').Take(3)

Comment: Its row consists of three columns. in that:   -1,-5,0

Comment: I should of said Take(3).  I suspect some of the other columns do not have double numbers.

Comment: gives the same error I tried. not even numbers in each column

Comment: Adding an exception handle will allow code to continue.

Comment: not show in console application.I'm using datagridview

Comment: Where do you display exceptions?  Console still works in a form project.  I usually put a Console.Readline() so console window doesn't close.

Comment: The code does not give an error. but the console does not apply anything to the screen when you click the button. how to show datagridview

Comment: I added a ReadLine() so you can see the errors.  You could add a textbox (should be multi-line) to the form to display the errors.

Comment: console does not work in windows form implementation

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn column;
            DataRow row;
            DataView view;
            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
            column.ColumnName = "max1";
            dt.Columns.Add(column);

Comment: column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Double");
            column.ColumnName = "max2";
            dt.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Double");
            column.ColumnName = "max3";
            dt.Columns.Add(column);

Comment: can we implement this

Comment: When you click the button does not come. don't we need to remove the console

Comment: Yes.  The Readline.  Jiust added the line so you could see the errors in the console.  You can just hit return in the console to continue.

Comment: no error, but the screen does not press anything datagridde

Comment: I just added to the datatable.  To see it on the form, you would need to add a control like a DataGridView  Then use datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: can you remove consoles